# Merging two byteArray in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arrays

I want to send the bitmap image through the bluetooth along with some other contents like char and int. The problem is to convert those things into single byte array. I tried by making it as two byte array and merging them but `copyTo` is not working. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: if you can display the code, it might help

Comment: byte[] buffer; byte[] thumbNail; i just need to merge this and have to transfer the byte array.. buffer consists of char,int and the thumbnail consists of bitmap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html).arraycopy method to copy one array into another

```
int lenA = arrayA.length;
int lenB = arrayB.length;
byte[] outArray = new byte[lenA + lenB];

System.arraycopy (arrayA, 0, outArray, 0, lenA);
System.arraycopy (arrayB, 0, outArray, lenA, lenB);
```

I haven't tested it, but should work.

**edit:**

And of course it's not recommended for big arrays. You're doubling data in memory in that way. I don't know what you're doing exactly with this data but if you can, use streaming instead.

Comment: I need to display the image in the textView tats it.. Streaming in the sense?

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream - depend what you want. And you asked about merging two byte arrays. I don't know what TextView has to it.

Comment: @dziobas The second argument in the last line is the index of the source array to start at, so shouldn't it be 0?  i.e. `System.arraycopy (arrayB, 0, outArray, lenA, lenB);`

Comment: @Bryan No, this code copies `arrayA` into `outArray`, then `arrayB` after `lenA` elements of `arrayA` into `outArray`.

Comment: @pawelzieba yes but arrayB starts at 0 and is lenB long. Second line is not correct. It should be as bmaupin indicated. You take all bytes in arrayB and add them to outArray, so by all bytes means you start at position 0 in arrayB, and not at position lenA as you wrote. Please correct the answer.